# Cypress override baseUrl in Docker container not working

Tags: javascript, azure, docker, cypress

Hello Im looking for help.|
I have a docker image that builds my Cypress tests in which I would like to override the baseURL. The problems is Cypress detects the baseUrl env variables but it doesn't apply them to the configuration and baseUrl still points to the localhost.

```
docker run \
      --name test \
      --env CI="true" \
      --env CYPRESS_BASE_URL="https://abrakada.com" \
      --env CYPRESS_baseUrl="https://abrakada.com" \
      --network="host" \
      --rm
```

```
FROM cypress/base:14.17.0

ARG TESTS_FOLDER=/opt/cypress-tests

ENV NODE_PATH=/opt:/usr/lib/node_modules:$TESTS_FOLDER/node_modules

WORKDIR $TESTS_FOLDER

COPY package.json ./package.json

RUN npm install && npm run cy:verify

COPY cypress.json ./cypress.json
COPY cypress ./cypress

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "cy:integration"]
```

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:3000",
  "chromeWebSecurity": false,
  "screenshotOnRunFailure": false,
  "videoUploadOnPasses": false
}
```

```
> npm run cy:info && ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run


> app-tests@1.0.0 cy:info /opt/cypress-tests
> cypress info

Displaying Cypress info...

Detected no known browsers installed


Environment Variables:
CYPRESS_BASE_URL: https://abrakada.com
CYPRESS_baseUrl: https://abrakada.com

Application Data: /root/.config/cypress/cy/development
Browser Profiles: /root/.config/cypress/cy/development/browsers
Binary Caches: /root/.cache/Cypress

Cypress Version: 8.1.0
System Platform: linux (Debian - 10.9)
System Memory: 6.23 GB free 389 MB
Cypress could not verify that this server is running:

  > http://localhost:3000

We are verifying this server because it has been configured as your `baseUrl`.
```

Answer (score 1):

fsss I hate it. Like always after few hours of troubleshooting I post a question and then after 15 min of the post I find the problem... Gosh..

Anyway.

My problem was that I had plugins configuration for extending config file which caused rest of configuration not being merged.

https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-extends

replaced
`return require('@bahmutov/cypress-extends')(config.configFile)`
with just `config` and baseUrl is being overwritten.